# Need to set centerAt to true before calling locate() method

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to allow the user to change the `extent` while the `Locator Widget` is tracking.  I defined the locator widget with the following code

```
var locateButtonLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
app.map.addLayer(locateButtonLayer);
var geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: app.map,
    graphicsLayer: locateButtonLayer,
    useTracking: true,
    setScale: false,
    centerAt: false
}, "LocateButton");
geoLocate.startup();
app.geoLocate = geoLocate;
```

If I don't set `setScale` and `centerAt` to false some browsers will reset the extent every few seconds.  If you user wants to re-center on their location the following code is called.

```
function customLocate() {
   require(["dojo/Deferred"], function(Deferred) {
       app.map.setScale(9000).then(function() {
           app.geoLocate.centerAt = true;
           app.geoLocate.locate().then(function(result) {
               app.geoLocate.centerAt = false;
           });
       });
   });
```

}

My issue is the locate() method will only center on the user's extent if I set a breakpoint on the `app.geoLocate.centerAt = false;` line.  Setting a breakpoint on any other line does not help.  I assume this has to do with the locate() returning a `promise` but I can't figure out how to fix the issue.  The code appeared to  run fine when I put it in the `Locator Widget` example sandbox at [Locator Widget Sandbox](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_locate)

EDIT:  The code works fine if I add an alert as shown below:

```
function customLocate() {
   require(["dojo/Deferred"], function(Deferred) {
       app.map.setScale(9000).then(function() {
           app.geoLocate.centerAt = true;
           app.geoLocate.locate().then(function(result) {
               alert("here");
               app.geoLocate.centerAt = false;
           });
       });
   });
```

}

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
  app.map.setScale(9000).then(function() {
   app.geoLocate.centerAt = true;
    on(app.map, "update-end", function(){
        app.geoLocate.locate().then(function() {
            on(map, "update-end", function(){
                app.geoLocate.centerAt = false;
            });
        });
    });
```

});

This solved the issue with the locate() method executing before the map was done updated but the `app.geoLocate.centerAt = false` line never gets executed so the map keeps re-centering every few seconds.  Evidently the locate() method prevents the `update-end` event from occurring when it is in tracking mode.

Comment: So it seems like you want to allow the user to turn on the LocateButton without automatically centering the map initially, but have a button that will do a 1-time center-and-zoom into the current location?

Comment: The user wants the first click on the icon to center-and-zoom and start the tracking.  They then want to be able to look at different parts of the map while the tracking is going on without center-and-zooming every time their location changes.  If they click on the icon after the tracking starts they want to center-and-zoom to their current location.  That is how my mapquest mobile app works.